# Setting a character variable which consists of this (') character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, special-characters

I want to set a variable to expressions like this `'word'` in SQL which consists of this (`'`) character.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? Normally you have to escape it by using two single quotes  ''word''

Comment: i'm using Microsoft DBMS , it uses '' character sets for character expressions . but i want something like this set @val = ''word'' i mean the value of the character variable would be 'word' instead of word

Comment: use '' instead of '
select 'aa''a'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server to show `'` use `''` into select

```
SELECT 'aa''a'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use variable with Single quotes as following :-

```
DECLARE @varName VARCHAR(50)
SET  @varName = '''word'''
SELECT @varName as colName
```

Output :- `'word'`

[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d34c/2)